# c9 to aws migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration

I have an app created in c9 IDE, e.g. (not real ones)

https://ide.c9.io/tobyuser/tobysapp

This runs and can navigate to my app at

https://tobysapp-tobyuser.c9users.io/

I'm required to migrate the app before c9's end of life

On doing this I now have

https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/ide/23447d5b47f343be............blah

This runs and the console tells me it has successfully connected to my DB on mongo

However, I do not know how to navigate to my app as per line 4 above, how would I find this out?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I needed to click Preview next to the Run button at the top of the IDE then select Preview Running Application